Midea U Shaped Window Unit
This may be too far outside the box but.......With some modifications, might the evaporator of a Midea U shaped window unit be tilted forward 90 degrees, to fit into a top hatch on a sailboat, or an RV, similar to a mini-split system?  The compressor would remain upright, and I have addressed the condensation issue on a similar installation, and of course it would void the warranty, but would it work?

The risk would be breaking/kinking/tearing the copper refrigerant lines. Refrigerant work may require licensing to be done legally in your jurisdiction.
There are videos on Youtube about separating the condenser and evaporator sides of a window AC to make them a half mini-split. It may be easier just to get the mini-split. A web-search suggests boat/RV mini-splits exist.
